# Multiple Values check and then return SQL

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table with columns:
Name and pizzaeaten
Now I want all the names who have eaten both pepperoni and mushroom
i.e. Not to include the ones that have only eaten pepperoni....or those who have only eaten mushroom.
But only those who have eaten both pepperoni and mushroom

Comment: Just a hint `GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT...`

Comment: What if they've eat pepperoni, mushroom, *and* extra cheese?  What if they at a pepperoni at one time, and a mushroom at another?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to do something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM 
    myTable 
WHERE 
    pizzaeaten = 'Pepperoni' AND name in 
    (
        SELECT name from myTable where pizzaeaten = 'mushroom'
    )
```

By means of the subquery you can thus obtain the results for both of the individual pizzaseaten.

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY and HAVING

```
   SELECT name from TableA
   Where pizzaeaten in ('pepperoni' ,   'mushroom')
   Group by name
   Having count(distinct pizzaeaten) >= 2
```

Comment: Use DISTINCT pizzaeaten  in case they have eaten mushroom twice.